# Modifying my nicad battery pack charger to charge nimh batts

Tags: repair

I've got a battery pack for one of my peripherals that recently died, so i took it apart to find half the (nicad) cells were dead (I tested each cell's voltage both with and without a load - the dead ones dropped off to zero with load).

So what i wish to do is replace them with nimh's. Apparently the easiest way to charge nimh's is at 10% of C (C being 2500mAh) for 15 hours at 1.5V per cell (i will have 10 cells in series).

Now the question:
I have a 15v power adaptor (correct voltage) but it is 400mA. I want to 'throttle' it to 250mA somehow. Is there some way i can do this with a diode or resistor or transistor or something?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are IC chips like the LM317 that vary the voltage to keep the current constant. But you can't do it with out building at least a small circuit. An alternative would be to put a potentiometer is series with the battery, but you would have to periodically adjust it to keep the current constant.

Comment: Is that similar to this?
http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Circuits/Power/add-on.html

Comment: Found a good example of that circuit:
http://sv1bsx.50webs.com/charger/charger.html

Comment: Chris, The second one's a good example. I might replace the fixed resistor with a pot  or better yet a pot in series with a fixed resistor to provide an absolute limit. With the pot you can adjust the current.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest method to limit current is with a series resistor. Be careful with the power rating of the resistor, though.

My understanding of battery charging is that the best method is to use a control circuit. Here are some examples of battery charging circuits that would perform better than a series resistor:

[Linear Tech LTC4060 NiMH/NiCd Battery Charging Circuit](http://www.coolcircuit.com/circuit/charger1/standalone_nimh_nicd_charger.html)

[Maxim  MAX712 NiCd/NiMH Battery Charging Circuit](http://www.qsl.net/eb4eqa/batt_charger/batt_charger.htm)

[National Semiconductor LM317 (as mentioned in another answer)](http://www.angelfire.com/electronic/hayles/charge1.html)

Comment: If i use a series resistor, would the resistor soak up part of the voltage, leaving less voltage for the batteries?

Comment: Yep. There would be a measurable voltage drop across the resistor.

Comment: Are we talking a lot of the voltage (eg 3 volts) being used by the resistor? Or only a little bit (eg < 1volt) ?

Comment: Oh, yeah. To answer your question, V=IR, so the voltage drop across a 60-ohm resistor at 250mA would be ~15V. :-) A resistor limits current, but is not best for a battery charging application.

Comment: I don't recommend using only a series resistor for a _constant current_ supply for use when changing batteries. The cost of a correct circuit is too cheap to accept unnecessary risk of damaging the batteries (which can have dangerous failure modes from over-charging or over-voltage while charging).